# replace numbers with token if numbers have whitespace on both side

Tags: python, string, replace, whitespace

the code below replaces numbers with the token NUMB:

`raw_corpus.loc[:,'constructed_recipe']=raw_corpus['constructed_recipe'].str.replace('\d+','NUMB')`

It works fine if the numbers have a space before and a space after, but creates a problem if the numbers are included in another string.

How do I modify the code so that it only replaces numbers with NUMB if the numbers are surrounded by a space on both sides? e.g. do not modify this string: "from url 500px", but do modify this string: "dishwasher 10 pods" to "dishwasher NUMB pods".

I'm not sure how to modify '\d+' to make this happen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just fix your regex for space:

```
\s\d+\s
```

or for any word boundary:

```
\b\d+\b
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried `' \d+ '` and that works! probably not "pythonic" though...